# Чтение формата BCD C#

Tags: c#, .net, дата, datetime

Есть устройство подключенное к шине ISA, которое периодически слушаю программой. Устройство передает пакет состоящий из 4х байт (32 бит), в пакете закодирована дата, я так понимаю в формате BCD (выделил красным полигоном), что интересно, устройство передает пакет не как массив байт, а как целое число (так реализовано в апи):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не знаю как правильно собрать эту информацию и в какой вид привести правильно и по фен шую. Больше всего склоняюсь к тому, что бы перевести значение в строку.

Допустим я битовыми сдвигами выделю каждую тетраду из целого числа и так же переведу в целое число. А дальше как, перевести в строку? Можно ли так делать? Или лучше перевести в байты и манипулировать уже ими?

Ну для примера я набросал что-то вроде такого псевдокода:

```
public struct MyDate
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public MyDate HwDate
    {
        get
        {
            date.Day = GetFrame(data, сдвиг1, сдвиг2);
            date.Month = GeFrame(data, сдвиг1, сдвиг2));
            date.Year = GetFrame(data, сдвиг1, сдвиг2);

            return date
        }
    }

// value - входящие данные от устройства
public int GetFrame(uint value, int length, int shift)
    {
        var mask = ((1U << length) - 1) << shift;
        var frame = value & mask;
        return (int) frame;
    }
```

Comment: Смотря что Вы собираетесь потом с этой информацией делать. Если куда-то выдать в строковом виде и забыть - то преобразовывайте в строку. А если потом с ней надо как-то манипулировать, с чем-то сравнивать - то лучше преобразовать в нормальный тип даты.

Comment: Да нет, просто условно вывести на экран. Я ппросто не пойму, мне выходит каждую тетраду вырезать из интеджера и формировать в строку?

Comment: ну, насколько я понимаю - да. Если, конечно, нет специальных библиотечных функций для BCD.

Comment: или вы можете это распарсить в DateTime и после форматировть как душе угодно.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!